# Deriving time-independent Schrodinger equation for $n$ qubit system with a constant Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-information, schroedinger-equation

I've seen some derivations of time-independent SE here on stack. Most of the answers involve a wave function with a variable $x$. However, it is not clear to me what one would do when we have a $n$ qubit system and a constant Hamiltonian $H$.
The general SE is
$$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle = H|\psi(t)\rangle.$$
If $H$ is constant can we still solve the above equation by assuming that $|\psi(t)\rangle$   can be written as product of some function $f(t)$ and a state $|\psi_0\rangle$ which does not have variables $x$ and $t$?
For example, does the following equation make sense?
$$|\psi(t)\rangle = f(t)|\psi_0\rangle.$$
If it does, is $f(t)$ just a global phase?

I pondered around and found $f(t)$ to be as follows
$$f(t) = Ce^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}Et}$$
where $C$ and $E$ are constants. Then to find $|\psi_0\rangle$, do I need to solve $H|\psi_0\rangle = E|\psi_0\rangle$?

To summarize, I would like to know the following:

1. Does it make sense to write $|\psi(t)\rangle = f(t)|\psi_0\rangle$.
2. Is $f(t)$ a global phase?
3. Is time-independent SE given by $H|\psi_0\rangle = E|\psi_0\rangle$ or  $H|\psi(t)\rangle = E|\psi(t)\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, $f(t)$ is usually called the [time evolution operator, or propagator](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Time_Dependent_Quantum_Mechanics_and_Spectroscopy_(Tokmakoff)/03%3A__Time-Evolution_Operator/3.01%3A_Time-Evolution_Operator) of the problem. The conventional notation for $f(t)$ is $U(t)$, which comes from the fact that $U(t)$ is a unitary operator.
2. Not necessarily. For a time-independent Hamiltonian $H$, the propagator takes the form
   $$U(t) = \exp(-iH t/\hbar),\tag{1}$$
   where $\exp$ is understood to be the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential). In general, this isn't just a global phase. This is clear if you write the action of $(1)$ in the eigenbasis of $H$, which I'll call $\{\vert n\rangle\}$:
   $$\vert\psi(t)\rangle=U(t)\vert\psi_0\rangle = \sum_n e^{-iE_n t/\hbar}\vert n \rangle\langle n \vert \psi_0\rangle,\tag{2}$$
   where $E_n$ are the corresponding eigenvalues. This is clearly not just a global phase. Do note, however, that if $H= E_0 1\!\!1$, you get
   $$\vert\psi(t)\rangle=U(t)\vert\psi_0\rangle =e^{-iE_0 t/\hbar}\vert \psi_0\rangle,\tag{3}$$
   i.e. *in the special case where $H$ is proportional to the identity operator*, the state just picks up a global phase.
3. Neither. The time-independent Schrodinger equation isn't directly concerned with the state of the system at any time. It's simply for finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian,
   $$H\vert n\rangle = E_n \vert n\rangle,\tag{4}$$
   which you can then use to predict the state. *After* finding the eigenvectors $\vert n\rangle$ and eigenvalues $E_n$, you can now proceed with calculating the time-evolved state $\vert \psi(t)\rangle $ using $(2)$. That's where the initial state comes in.

Comment: Hi Sahand, thank you so much for your detailed reply. I would like to make a few clarifications. First, to find the solution $|\psi(t)\rangle$ we solve the time-independent SE which is $H|n\rangle = E_n |n \rangle$ and then evolve $|n\rangle$ it with $U(t)$?
Second, if $|\psi_0\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $H$ then (2) is just $e^{-i E t / \hbar}|\psi_0\rangle$. Also, in (2) you wrote $U(t)$ to be independent of time, is this a typo?

Comment: @MonteNero 1 - No. You find $\vert n \rangle$ and $E_n$, and then evolve *the initial state* $\vert \psi_0 \rangle$  with them à la Eq.$(2)$. The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are just convenient tools for evaluating Eq.$(2)$ with the initial state in question (which can be completely separate of $\vert n\rangle$).
2 - Yes, in the special case where $\vert \psi_0\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $H$, the evolution is just a global phase. But that's just a special case, $\vert \psi_0\rangle$ doesn't have to be an eigenstate.
3 - Yes, that was a typo. The exponent has $t$ in it. It has been fixed.

Comment: Thank you @Sahand Tabatabaei. If I find all $|n\rangle$ and $E_n$, why would I want to evolve an initial state $|\psi_0\rangle$ with $U(t)$? I could just set $|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-i E_n t /\hbar} |n\rangle$. This is a valid solution to the general SE, no? To obtain a more general solution I just take a linear combination of $e^{-i E_n t /\hbar} |n\rangle$ for $n=0, 1, ..., N$. Please forgive me for naive questions. I have zero training in physics.

Comment: @MonteNero. Sure, you can use a linear combination of $e^{-i E_n t/\hbar}\vert n \rangle$, with the coefficients being determined by the initial condition of the DE $\vert \psi_0\rangle$. That's exactly what Eq.$(2)$ is in the first place!

Comment: that makes total sense now!

Comment: can't upvote, not enough reputation in phys stack :(

Comment: @MonteNero Don't worry about it, as long as I could help ;)